# JavaScript - Undo sorting of an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, sorting, lodash

I'm making a sortable table. The table data is from an array of objects. I need to be able to sort the array based on the properties

an object looks like this:

```
{
"AbsenceReservationID": 7220,
"Name": "DGM",
"Code": "ARBEIDSONGEVAL WP",
"RequestState": "Goedgekeurd",
"From": "2017-03-21T00:00:00+01:00",
}
```

I'm using **lodash**, so I can easily sort my array using the following syntax:

*asc:*

```
myArr = _.sortBy(myArr , "Name");
```

*desc:*

```
myArr = _.sortBy(myArr , "Name").reverse;
```

However I'm stuck at the last sorting method. I need to be able to undo the sort but I can't figure out a good way to do this. Here's how it would work:

- 1st click - sort asc
- 2nd click - sort desc
- 3rd click - remove sorting
  on this property

I think the hard part is when the user sorts on mutliple properties, so for example

How can I achieve this removal of a property sort?

Comment: What is your initial sort(by name, date, ...)?

Comment: add another property for original sorting and use it to revert sorting.

Comment: Keep an array with all the sort properties

Comment: @giaco there is no initial sort atm, it just prints the array how It's received from the API call

Comment: keep original array untouched (myArr)... use a copy of the array for whatever purpose you need (copy) ... ... so, `copy=myArr.slice()` - original order. `copy=_.sortBy(myArr.slice() , "Name");` sorted copy ... etc

Comment: apply sort like `var sorted = myArr.slice().sort((a,b) => whateverLogic)`

Comment: just remember ( store)  the original table before any sorting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically have three choices:

1. Don't offer the "unsorted" option
2. Remember the original order (perhaps by adding a property for it), and for the "unsorted" option, sort on that property

   For instance, you can add an `originalIndex` property:

   ```
   _.forEach(myArr, function(e, i) { e.originalIndex = i; });
   ```

   Then `myArr = _.sortBy(myArr, "originalIndex");` will get the original order back.
3. Keep the original array somewhere (since `_.sortBy` creates a copy), and use the original array again when you want the "unsorted" version

Comment: Your answer is very-very helpful. I was trying to do this a very long time and only your answer helped me. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 5):

You can use to create an original copy:

```
var oldArr = myArr.slice(); // gives you a new copy.
```

You can use `oldArr` after sorting.

Answer (score 0):

**Where are you getting the data from initially? (service)**

If it is coming from a service call - would recommend simply re-calling that service and setting the data equal to the data retrieved again.

If you don't want to make a call to the service again, simply create two objects in JS *sortingData* and *unsortedData*. Then when you use the lodash method, simply apply it only to the *sortingData* array. On the third click, do

```
sortingData = unsortedData;
```

**Where are you getting the data from initially? (manually created)**

The same approach of having two objects applies here. Once the data has been created, before you allow sorting to be done, set the *unsortedData* to the *data* that you have generated. e.g.

```
unsortedData = data;
```